# React: Calling parent's method through inheritance

Tags: reactjs

**I understand that inheritance is not recommended by FB. The ideal way is composition.Since the structure of this app was set up previously by senior dev years ago, I don't have the power to change it as a junior dev**

I am trying to invoke a parent component's method in child component. I have a parent component ParentComp, that looks like following:

```
export default class ParentComp extends GrandParentComp {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.foo();
  }
}
```

The parent component is bundled like a module with webpack, so i cant pass child component as property.

And the child component that looks like this:

```
import ParentComp from './ParentComp'

export default class ChildComp extends ParentComp {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to trigger parent component's method through inheritance? Because "Hello World" was never print on the console.

**What I have to tried**: I tried to look up FB's document, but they simply skipped explaining inheritance saying it is not recommended.

**What I need help with**: If I have to do it through inheritance, what is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a typo in `class ChildComp extends ParentCOmp`. Apart from it, you can simply access the parent function in child using `this` keyword as if it is its own function.

```
class ParentComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.foo();
  }
}

class ChildComp extends ParentComp {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.foo();
  }
  render() {
    return "Hello Codesandbox";
  }
}
```

[**Demo Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/07j6n1lzn)

Comment: sorry for the typo,  The line within child's constructor is actually this: this.foo = this.foo.bind(this). I thought I dont need a seperate function to trigger the parent method? The function name is actually foo, i forgot to change it when copy my code to SO.

Comment: with `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)`, you are not calling the parent function but assigning a reference of the parent function to `this.foo` a class variable in child

Comment: so i still need to create a function within child component to trigger this.foo()?

Comment: Wherever in child you want to call the parent function foo, you would just write `this.foo()`, You don't need to create a new function to call it. the above code that I mentioned is just a sample.

Comment: @aDev, is the problem solved or you have some questions

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parent method to the child as a property.

```
export default class ParentComp extends GrandParentComp {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    foo() {
      console.log("Hello World")
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ChildComp foo={this.foo()}
        );
    }
  }
```

Call it in the child component.

```
export default class ChildComp extends ParentCOmp {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: The parent component was wrapped up as a module in the web packer. I understand that composition is the ideal way, but  This is what I would do if I was the one who started this project, but this project is already half done and they are doing it through inheritance

Comment: @aDev my bad didn't really get that was the problem!